# How to execute a transaction on mysql using JDBC driver without manipulation auto-commit mode

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I'm working on a JAVA dynamic web project. I have one shared java.sql.Connection object to handle every database query. At a point, I require 3 sql update statements to be executed atomically. That is, if one statement fails to execute, then the effects are rolled back. To be more precise, this is the pseudo-code for what I want to achieve-

```
  try {
    create transaction T
    T.execute(statement1)
    T.execute(statement2)
    T.execute(statement3)
    T.commit()
  } catch(SQLException) {
    T.rollback()
  }
```

I have googled about this problem, and everyone seems to suggest to set the java.sql.Connection auto-commit mode to false, and after executing the transaction, setting it to true again. But if I do that, then all the query executions, that might have been executed from another threads would also be added to this transaction, as long as auto-commit mode is false. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: The only real solution is to not share a connection concurrently. Use a connection pool, obtain a connection, disable autocommit, do work, commit and close it (so it's returned to the pool).

Comment: It's not a good idea to use one connection for all threads. http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/devguide/cdevconcepts89498.html